# Average from a same row - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have a table which is having 5 columns. I need to find the average using SQL for every row (ignoring the 0 columns). Can I get some help.

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 AVERAGE
  1    2    3   4     5   3
  4    0    4   0     4   4
  3    0    0   0     9   6
  7    0    0   0     0   7
```

Sorry the table did not come clearly. I need the average to be calculated for each row for any non-zero values. For eg: the 5 cols had (4,0,4,0,4) I do not need the average as 12/5, I need the average as 12/3 =4. Basically divide it by the number of nonzero values. It is not always divided by 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little trickier than first glance. Without using pivot tables (which is another method, but probably overkill here), you can sum the columns and then divide by the number of non-zero columns. The trick is when every column is zero, you need to cater for that specifically otherwise you will get a divide by zero error:

```
SELECT
  COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5,
  CASE WHEN (COL1 = 0 AND COL2 = 0 AND COL3 = 0 AND COL4 = 0 AND COL5 = 0) 
    THEN 0
    ELSE 
        (COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + COL4 + COL5)
        / (
            CASE WHEN COL1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN COL2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN COL3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN COL4 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
            CASE WHEN COL5 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        )
    END AS AVERAGE
FROM stats
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10e70/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `CROSS APPLY`. You must be carefull with precision when calculating average. For example, what is your expected average for values 1, 1, 2, 2, 3? `AVG` will return 1, but if you  expect it to be 1.8, you should use floating point datatype before calculating average

```
with cte as (
    select * from
        (values
            (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            ,(4, 0, 4, 0, 4)
            ,(3, 0, 0, 0, 9)
            ,(7, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            ,(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
        ) t(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5)
)

select
    *
from
    cte
    cross apply (
        select 
            average = avg(val) --change to avg(val * 1.0) to get floating point numeric
        from 
            (values (COL1), (COL2), (COL3), (COL4), (COL5)) t(val) 
        where val > 0
    ) q
```